# Send runtime parameter value to the jQuery's ON method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple button. and I need to send data to the handler when clicked.

So I have this code using the [**ON overload method**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) :

```
.on( events [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

I've created this sample :

```
var aaa="john";

function greet(event) { alert("Hello "+event.data.name); }

$("button").on("click", { name: aaa}, greet);

setTimeout(function (){aaa="paul"},2000)
```

But after waiting 2 sec , I still see:  `"Hello John"`

So I assume that the `aaa` value is bounded at interpretation time.

**Question :**

How can I change the code so that after 2 seconds it will alert : `Hello Paul` ?

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/ohAJihi/2/edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way is to use an object literal. You can pass it as event data and keep a reference that you modify later:

```
var greetData = {
    name: "john"
};

function greet(event)
{
    alert("Hello " + event.data.name);
}

$("button").on("click", greetData, greet);

setTimeout(function() {
    greetData.name = "paul";
}, 2000);
```

You will find an updated JS Bin [here](http://jsbin.com/ohAJihi/3/edit).

Comment: I used the same pattern as the code in your question, but the object does not have to be global. You can close over it and expose it through a function, or simply use `data()` to associate it with a DOM element.

Answer (score 3):

[Frédéric Hamidi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18507233/338208) is better. Will leave this just as an alternative.

If you change it so that you pass a function that loads the name instead of the name it self it will work:

```
var aaa="john";

function getName() {
  return aaa;
}

function greet(event) { alert("Hello "+event.data.name()); }
$("button").on("click", { name: getName}, greet);

setTimeout(function (){aaa="paul";},2000);
```

http://jsbin.com/ohAJihi/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

It is a little confusing to understand what are you 
trying to achieve. If you are using setTimeout; theres no need to use a button onclick handler.
Secondly, the scope of the setTimeout function is always the window object. So if you need to access the value from your object, please create a reference of it and use in the setTimeout function.

Comment: the setTimeout is just to simulate a delay. and setTimeout to  window object related info is only for the `this` value. ( very unrelated to my question)